# Websocket: Cannot establish a connection with basic websocket server

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, websocket, telnet, ratchet

I've tried very basic websocket tutorial using ratchet php, exactly as shown in http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world

Code for websocket server:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'chat.php';

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use HHWS\Chat;


$server = IoServer::factory(
    new Chat(),
    8080
);

$server->run();
```

To run the server I did:

```
$ php ws-server.php
```

And to test the connection with the server I did:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 8080
```

This worked perfectly fine when tested LOCALLY. Users can chat using multiple telnet terminals.

I then uploaded the code to live server. And the tried running the server. 
Then tried to connect to this server using telnet just like before, it couldn't connect.
All it shows is "Trying.." message and then " Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out".

I don't know why this is happening, and what the problem is. The code is exactly the same. And this is very basic hello world example I'm doing. Can anyone help me on this.
Do using "Websockets" have any other requirements on the live server to work.

**Update:**
Actually, the live server is **Amazon EC2**; does this require setting up additional things for websocket to work?

Comment: Is port 8080 open on your live server?

Comment: @KristenJukowski: what do you mean 8080 port is open? That script should have opened server on that port, isn't it?

Comment: Without knowing your server/hosting environment on your live server, it's hard to tell. Even if the service was indeed started and running on port 8080, you could get a timeout if the server's firewall is blocking that port.

Comment: there are some tips in their docs, maybe it helps: http://socketo.me/docs/deploy

Comment: @KristenJukowski: actually, the server is Amazon ec2. I'm testing it via Putty. I don't know pretty much about firewalls and stuffs..does anything need to be set up before websocket can work?

Comment: AWS EC2 will block port 8080 by default. You need to allow the port in your Security Groups under the Inbound tab.

Comment: Thanks! just added a port on the security groups and it did work

Comment: Tried with port 8080 it couldn't. Will try to answer  [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52848607/7713811) to the posted question